# While html value is loaded alert dont show it

Tags: jquery

I am using a php file to retrieve some value from mysql.
The result looks like this: `4.7647058823529`.

i am loading this result with my code bellow to a div and it works great.

1. if i am using alert to get this value alert dont show the value.
2. how can i transform tis value to looks like this: `4.7` and not `4.7647058823529`

and why alert dont show up this val?

```
$(".getfinalrate").load("update.php?tpid=" + id);
var res = $(".getfinalrate").text();
$(".getfinalrate").fadeIn();
alert (res);
```

My php code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['tpid']))
{

require "connection.php";

$videid = $_GET['tpid'];
$id = mysql_escape_string($videid);


$thecounter = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS sumury FROM user WHERE id = '$id'"); 
$numm = mysql_fetch_array($thecounter); 
$getallrecords = $numm["vote_action"];

$queryf="SELECT SUM(vote_action) AS `total` from user WHERE id = '$id'";
$resultf=mysql_query($queryf);
while($rowf=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultf))
$totals = $rowf['total'];

if ($getallrecords > $totals){
$finalratepoints = $getallrecords / $totals;
echo $finalratepoints;  
}else{
$finalratepoints = $totals / $getallrecords;
echo $finalratepoints;
}
}
?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: We should see the PHP code to tell how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code isn't executing the way you think it is:

```
$(".getfinalrate").load("update.php?tpid=" + id);
var res = $(".getfinalrate").text();
$(".getfinalrate").fadeIn();
alert(res);
```

You see, `.load()` is asynchronous.  So before it completes, the rest of this code continues to execute.  So `res` will be empty if `$(".getfinalrate").text()` is empty when this code begins executing.

You need to think about this asynchronously.  When `.load()` executes, it's going to continue in its own thread.  Anything that needs to happen in response to that thread needs to happen in a callback to be executed by that thread.  `.load()` supplies an argument for such a callback function:

```
$(".getfinalrate").load("update.php?tpid=" + id, function () {
    var res = $(".getfinalrate").text();
    $(".getfinalrate").fadeIn();
    alert(res);
});
```

In this structure, the anonymous inline function will be called by `.load()` when it completes its AJAX request.  Any code that's after this call to `.load()` will continue immediately, but the code within the function is deferred until the asynchronous call completes.

Answer (score 3):

Because [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is *asynchronous*, so:

```
$(".getfinalrate").load("update.php?tpid=" + id); // *Starts* the load
var res = $(".getfinalrate").text();              // Gets the text *BEFORE* the load completes
```

So `res` ends up having whatever the first `.getfinalrate` element had in it *before* the `load`.

The solution is to use `load`'s callback function:

```
$(".getfinalrate").load("update.php?tpid=" + id, function() {
    // This function is called when the load is complete
    var res = $(".getfinalrate").text();
    $(".getfinalrate").fadeIn();
    alert (res);
});
```

> how can i transform tis value to looks like this: `4.7` and not `4.7647058823529`

It's best to ask **one** question per question on Stack Overflow.

Assuming you want `res` as a number the answer is:

```
res = Math.floor(4.76747 * 10) / 10;
```

If you want it as a string, you might want to do this:

```
res = (Math.floor(4.76747 * 10) / 10).toFixed(1)
```

...to ensure there are not tiny little fractional bits lying around because floating point is not perfectly precise.

Comment: @IreneT.: Sorry, I got distracted by the second question. See the update.

Answer (score 1):

How you want get values from other page requires Ajax.

```
$.get("update.php?tpid="+id, function(response){
   //Alert Response
   alert(response);
   $(".getfinalrate").html(response);

}):
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to do synchron AJAX request. Have a look at this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ especially on the async option. But beware, the whole site will be blocked until the load is done.
2. `var res = $(".getfinalrate").text();

   res = Math.floor(res * 10)/10;
   alert(res);`